# Change @ManagedResource objectName dynamically

Tags: java, spring, jmx, spring-3

I am creating prototype beans programatically/dynamically. I want those beans after initiation to be in the jmx console. How I can distinguish between them? I am using anotations in order to add my beans to the jmx and I have

```
@ManagedResource(objectName="bean:name=MybBean")
```

I need to inject the objectName dynamically. Any idea how could I do it?

Here's my jmx configuration:

```
<context:mbean-export server="mbeanServer" />

<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean" />

<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter"
        lazy-init="false">

        <property name="beans">
            <map>
                <entry key="Server:name=HttpAdaptor">
                    <bean class="mx4j.tools.adaptor.http.HttpAdaptor">
                        <property name="port" value="8000" />
                        <property name="host" value="0.0.0.0" />
                        <property name="processor">
                            <bean class="mx4j.tools.adaptor.http.XSLTProcessor" />
                        </property>

                    </bean>
                </entry>                
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="listeners">
            <list>
                <!--

                -->
                <bean class="com.fixgw.jmx.HttpAdaptorMgr">
                    <property name="mbeanServer" ref="mbeanServer" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <bean id="sessionMDB" class="com.fixgw.mdb.SessionMDB"
        scope="prototype" lazy-init="true">
        <constructor-arg ref="0" />
        <constructor-arg ref="0" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a a JMX naming strategy to do this.  At work we use an interface:

```
public interface RuntimeJmxNames {
    /** this is the name= part of the object name */
    public String getJmxName();
    /** this sets the folders as 00=FirstFolder,01=Second */
    public String[] getJmxPath();
}
```

I've posted the code to implement the [RuntimeMetadataNamingStrategy naming strategy](http://pastebin.com/XyYSiV2e).

And then something like the following Spring beans:

```
<bean id="jmxAttributeSource"
 class="org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource" />

<bean id="jmxAssembler"
    class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler">
    <property name="attributeSource" ref="jmxAttributeSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmxNamingStrategy" class="com.j256.jmx.RuntimeMetadataNamingStrategy">
    <property name="attributeSource" ref="jmxAttributeSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="mbeanExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
    <property name="autodetect" value="true" />
    <property name="assembler" ref="jmxAssembler" />
    <property name="namingStrategy" ref="jmxNamingStrategy" />
    <property name="ensureUniqueRuntimeObjectNames" value="false" />
    <property name="excludedBeans" ref="excludedJmxBeans" />
</bean>
```

In your code you do something like:

```
@ManagedResource(objectName = "foo.com:name=replaced", description = "...")
public class Foo implements RuntimeJmxNames {
    ...
    public String getJmxName() {
        // here's where you can make the name be dynamic
        return toString();
    }
    @Override
    public String[] getJmxPath() {
        return new String[] { "folder" };
    }
}
```

Here's the Spring documentation on [JMX naming](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jmx.html) although I'm not 100% sure it covers the custom naming stuff.

Also, my [SimpleJMX package](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) does a this as well.  It uses a [JmxSelfNaming interface](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/javadoc/simplejmx/com/j256/simplejmx/common/JmxSelfNaming.html) which allows each instance of an object to define it's own bean-name to make them unique and works well with Spring.

Comment: But the bean name is hardcoded in the class.. I need it to be dynamic I will set it on the creation of the instance

Comment: So in your `getJmxName()` method, it can do whatever it would like programmatically.  It can do it's `toString()` method or spit out whatever makes it unique.  I've edited the answer to make this more obvious.

Comment: com.j256.jmx.RuntimeMetadataNamingStrategy I need to get that lib eh?

Comment: That lead to other error:  No bean named '0' is defined. I have editted the way my mbean looks like in the configuration file

Comment: Dont forget I am creating this prototype bean dynamically so this is like a 'placeholder' arguments.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem there rayman.  We use the `MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler` which may be easier than the hard wiring that you are doing.  Who is talking about a bean named '0'?

Comment: I said this is an error I am getting when I am using your technic: aused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [sessionMDB] with key 'sessionMDB'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionMDB' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '0' is define
... 14 more

Comment: Oh, I see @rayman.  In your XML you have:  <bean id="sessionMDB" class="com.fixgw.mdb.SessionMDB"><constructor-arg ref="0" />....  That should be `value=0` not `ref=0`.  That was broken before, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13974/discussion-between-rayman-and-gray)

Comment: Works awesome.
I've implemented your solution using Annotations since I don't like xml config.
Here's the implementation: https://pastebin.com/vDp9rvBD

Comment: You might want to look at my SimpleJMX package @hmojica.  http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/

Answer (score 16):

You can do this by just implementing [`org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.SelfNaming`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/export/naming/SelfNaming.html):

```
@Component("MyPrototypeScopedBeanName")
@ManagedResource     
public class MyPrototypeScopedBeanName implements SelfNaming
{
    @Override
    public ObjectName getObjectName() throws MalformedObjectNameException {
        return new ObjectName("com.foobar", "name", this.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is easy to use and works well with `<context:mbean-export />`.

Comment: No need for MBeanExporter, Postconstruct and properties in my case