# Dynamically instantiate JMX MBeans

Tags: java, spring, jmx

I have a white label/multi-tennant server providing the same services, but branded for multiple customers. I want to use JMX to monitor the status of each customer (nbr of calls, nbr of errors, etc).

I know how to use Spring JMX annotations to wire up my POJOs (per the code below). What I really want is one MBean per customer, but because the customers are dynamically loaded up at server startup time I don't know how to wire this up using annotations.

Is this possible?  If not, is it possible to instantiate my MBeans at startup time ?

```
@Component
@ManagedResource(objectName = "TravelAPI:name=Customer") 
public class CustomerStatus extends GeneralCustomerStatus {

    @ManagedAttribute
    String customerId;
    .
    .
    .


}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What I really want is one MBean per customer, but because the customers are dynamically loaded up at server startup time I don't know how to wire this up using annotations.

What we do is to have the entity that is actually instantiating your dynamic objects, register them with JMX via the `MBeanExporter`.  We inject the `MBeanExporter` instance into the factory entity and then call `MBeanExporter.registerManagedResource(...)`.

For example we do something like:

```
...
mbeanExporter.registerManagedResource(beanInstance);
...

@Required
public void setMbeanExporter(MBeanExporter mbeanExporter) {
    this.mbeanExporter = mbeanExporter;
}
```

We also use a `NamingPolicy` so that the dynamic objects can provide their own names to make them unique.  See more details about that here:

> [Change @ManagedResource objectName dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506486/change-managedresource-objectname-dynamically/11506648#11506648)

As an aside, my [SimpleJMX package](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) has some code to help with dynamic objects.